# Safari Extensions keep on getting deleted

Tags: high-sierra, safari-extensions

I recently upgraded to High Sierra and I liked the upgrade too but the most annoying thing is that the safari extensions which I download from the official Apple website keep on getting deleted by **itself** I have tried to fix the problem by trying the following stuff:

Deleting  ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/Extensions.plist
Deleting  ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/

So can someone help me around with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely: Another case of self-corrupting but never correcting caches.

- Close Safari.
- Remove ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari (the entire folder  and its contents, where mismatching copies of the extension pile up with a pattern of name-1.safariextension, name-2.safariextension .)
- Restart Safari.
- Download the extensions you need once more.
- Extensions should stay put again.